# Testing SpringCloudFunction which handles the SQSEvent

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, spring-cloud-function

The event request passed to the Lambda through FunctionInvoker getting converted to empty object

Unable to find the where exactly the conversion is happening but I could see in the log that input gets printed by the class AWSLambdaUtil, however when the request reaches the Lambda function its gets emptied

```
 System.setProperty("MAIN_CLASS", MyApplication.class.getName());
 System.setProperty("spring.cloud.function.definition", "SQSEventHandler");
 String jsonEventPayload = Files.readString(ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:sqs-event/sqsEvent.json").toPath());

 SQSEvent event = objectMapper.readValue(jsonEventPayload,SQSEvent.class);

 InputStream targetStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(event));
 ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 FunctionInvoker invoker = new FunctionInvoker();
 invoker.handleRequest(targetStream, output, null);`
```

Comment: AWSTypesMessageConverter serialize the Object as empty from the byte[] thats being passed. but could not understand why its not being converted to the corresponding SQSEvent object

Answer (score 0):

When I passed the byteArray directly from the jsonEventPayload String object the issue got resolved.